# Writing a document-like Text

Tags: graphics, style, text, writing

Imagine I have the following code

```
Graphics[{LightBlue, Rectangle[], Black, Text["Hello", {.1, .9}]}]
```

[image]

If I had more text to the `Text` object I get, for example

```
Graphics[{LightBlue, Rectangle[], Black, Text["Hello, my name is Sam", {.1, .9}]}]
```

[image]

But I would like the text to keep writing on the right of the first "anchor point". That is, something like

[image]

How can I do this? Maybe there is a way of fixing the `Text` coordinates to be on the left?

Comment: Use 3rd argument of Text: `Text["Hello, my name is Sam", {.1, .9}, {-1, 0}]`

Comment: `Framed[Text[Style["This is my text", TextAlignment -> Left]], 
 Background -> LightBlue]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Framed[
   Text[
   Style["This is my text", TextAlignment -> Left]], 
 Background -> LightBlue,
 ImageSize -> {500, 100}]
```